# CERK07- SPOJ - bitmask in bfs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graph, breadth-first-search, bitmask

I am trying to solve SPOJ's problem CERK07- KeyTask. I learnt a new concept here using bitmask in bfs. I am trying to implement my code in java . I am having problem in the `else if(val == 'R'|| val == 'G' || val == 'B' || val =='Y')` condtion (i.e when I encounter a door) and I want to check whether have the key for that door. My intelliJ IDE suggests that the condition `case 'B': if((umask & 0x2) == 1 )` is always false. Same case for all the other doors below this condition. I don’t know why this is happening ?

```
 public static int bfs(int[] start, char[][] grid, int[][][] d) {
        int m = grid.length;
        int n = grid[0].length;

        Queue<int[]> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(new int[]{start[0], start[1], 0});

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int[] curr = q.poll();
            int x = curr[0];
            int y = curr[1];
            int umask = curr[2];
            final int[][] shifts = {
                    {-1, 0},
                    {0, 1},
                    {1, 0},
                    {0, -1}
            };
            for (int[] shift : shifts) {
                int dx = x + shift[0];
                int dy = y + shift[1];

                if (isValid(dx, dy, m, n) && grid[dx][dy] != '#') {
                    if (grid[dx][dy] == 'X') {
                        return d[x][y][umask] + 1;
                    }
                    if (d[dx][dy][umask] == -1) {
                        char val = grid[dx][dy];
                        if (val == 'r' || val == 'b' || val == 'g' || val == 'y') {
                            int vmask = umask;
                            if (val == 'r') vmask |= 0x1;
                            else if (val == 'b') vmask |= 0x2;
                            else if (val == 'g') vmask |= 0x4;
                            else vmask |= 0x8;

                            q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, vmask});
                            d[dx][dy][umask] = d[x][y][umask] + 1;
                            d[dx][dy][vmask] = d[dx][dy][umask];
                        } else if (val == 'R' || val == 'G' || val == 'B' || val == 'Y') {
                            switch (val) {
                                case 'R':
                                    if ((umask & 0x1) == 1) q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, umask});
                                    break;
                                case 'B':
                                    if ((umask & 0x2) == 1) q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, umask});
                                    break;
                                case 'G':
                                    if ((umask & 0x4) == 1) q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, umask});
                                    break;
                                case 'Y':
                                    if ((umask & 0x8) == 1) q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, umask});
                                    break;
                            }
                            d[dx][dy][umask] = d[x][y][umask] + 1;
                        } else {
                            q.add(new int[]{dx, dy, umask});
                            d[dx][dy][umask] = d[x][y][umask] + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `(umask & 0x2)` expression is either 0 or 2. It cannot be 1, hence IntelliJ IDEA warns you about this. Similarly `(umask & 0x4)` is either 0 or 4 and `(umask & 0x8)` is either 0 or 8. It's likely that you wanted to write `(umask & 0x2) == 2` and so on. This way your condition becomes correct and the warning disappears.

Comment: why is it so ? I want to check using bitwise AND  `umask & 0010` == 1  that  the second  bit is set for 'Blue' door. Why doesn't result in 1 ?

Comment: @AbhishekDasgupta because `System.out.println(0b1111 & 0b0010);` will print `2` and `System.out.println(0b1101 & 0b0010);` will print `0`. If you want to test that a bit is set, compare the result to `0`. If it's zero, the bit is not set, if it's non-zero, the bit is set.